# Android application is not running in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Galileo for android developing . Almost a newbie. My Eclipse was running fine with android SDK before I setting up OS . I am using Windows 7 32 bit . After new  installation of OS , I reset adt plugin . Now , the android programs starts fine but the code is not working . I just found a ClassNotFoundException in a program . What's the problem here ? Can anyone give me a solution ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: post some code and/or logcat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add the android sdk lib? If you didn't Eclipse will not find the Android classes. Go to Project property Android and choose your API level.

Answer (score 0):

U need install ADT Plugin and restart IDE, after u need set path of android sdk, probally on home folder/android-sdk-windows(linux).

It's finish, you need create Android Project (not a Java project) and choose API level and need create ADT Emulator to this API in Manager Devices (new icon in eclipse after install ADT Plugin).

Thanks.